# prompt box html not let execute further execution of code if pressed cancel

Tags: html, prompt

I am using prompt box and if I press cancel without entering data in textbox of promptbox then the my further logic after prompt box do not execute ;if I press ok the that code is executed. how to make my code execute even if I press cancel in promtbox as it happen after I enter data and press ok ?

```
var textentered=prompt("Enter text/int:","");
if(textentered.length > 0){

    alert(textentered);
}

// this is just example code below the promptbox which is not executed after i press //cancel in prompt box
text=[];
array=[];
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem if when `prompt` is canceled, `textentered` would be `null`.
Thus, the `if(textentered.length > 0)` will fail.

You'll have to change the code to act differently if `textentered` is `null`.
Like below example.

```
var textentered = prompt("Enter text/int:", "");
if (textentered) { //pressed ok OR if text is not empty
    alert(textentered);
} else { //pressed cancel
    textentered = ""; //is null. change to empty string
}
//at this point, non-empty text means that user pressed the ok button
```

Comment: no i thing u didn't get my question my question is when i press cancel ,as it does not math my if condition it wil not enter and execute the remaining code followed after if condition ;but this does not happen if i press cancel my remaining code after if condition will not be executed and this should not happen

Comment: or i thing i am not able to understand wht u r saying?

Comment: I missed the point of your question, sorry. The answer has been updated.

Comment: no still not executing the code neither it goes in else part when i press cancel

Comment: The above code works on Firefox 15 and Chrome 22. The problem is likely somewhere in your code *before* any `alert` of `console.log` statement. Check the *Error Console*.